# Googleフォームでsubmit後にサンクスページに遷移させたい

Tags: google-apps-script

**▼目的**
ホームページのお問い合わせページにGoogleフォームを埋め込んで利用したいのですが、お問い合わせ完了数をGoogle Analyticsで計測するため、submit後に特定のページ（サンクスページ）に遷移させたい。

**▼調べたこと**
以下の2サイトが関連するサイトだと思います。

・知恵袋
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14161605959
・hello-world.jp.net
https://blog.hello-world.jp.net/javascript/878/#i-2

**▼調べた上で行ったこと**
①お問い合わせページ「https://example.com/contact」のHTML記入欄に、以下のようなGoogleフォームのタグを記入。お問い合わせフォームは正しく埋め込まれていることは確認済み。

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/~~~/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="1634" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">読み込んでいます...</iframe>
```

②サンクスページを「https://example.com/thanks」として、調べたことを参考にし以下のコードを作成。

```html
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" 
style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) 
{window.location='http://example.com/thanks'}"></iframe>
<form action="https://example.com/thanks" method="POST" id="ss-form" 
target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true">
```

**▼ご質問**
Q1. 上記コードはどこに貼ったら良いのでしょうか？
Q2. 上記コードは合っているでしょうか？

以上、素人なご質問で恐縮ですが、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" 
style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) 
{window.location='http://example.com/thanks'}"></iframe>
```

はhead内に貼って

```html
<form action="ここにグーグルフォームのURL" method="POST" id="ss-form" 
target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true">
```

はbody内ですが、actionのところにフォームのURLを貼ります。

あとは`entry.012345`←の数字の部分をサイトから抜き出してきて、input のタグの部分に`name="entry.012345"`みたいな感じに入れてください。

多分そんな感じで動くと思います。

Comment: これは google form の仕組みを誤解した回答ですね。  onsubmit イベントは発生しませんよ。